# JDBC - Oracle ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jboss

I'm getting an Exception while trying to insert a row in oracle table.
I'm using ojdbc5.jar for oracle 11
this is the sql i'm trying

```
INSERT INTO rule_definitions(RULE_DEFINITION_SYS,rule_definition_type,
rule_name,rule_text,rule_comment,rule_message,rule_condition,rule_active,
rule_type,current_value,last_modified_by,last_modified_dttm,
rule_category_sys,recheck_unit,recheck_period,trackable)
VALUES(RULE_DEFINITIONS_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

and i get following Exception. Any help will be appreciated.

```
java.ljava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.computeBasicInfo(OracleSql.java:950)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.getSqlKind(OracleSql.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1212)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.(T4CPreparedStatement.java:28)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.allocatePreparedStatement(T4CDriverExtension.java:68)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:2961)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:5874)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:232)
    at com.gehcit.platform.cds.common.util.db.DBWrapper.executeInsertOracleReturnPK(DBWrapper.java:605)
```

Comment: I think you should paste the code you are executing this SQL with.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Oracle Metalink (Oracle's support site - Note ID 736273.1) I found that this is a bug in JDBC adapter (version 10.2.0.0.0 to 11.1.0.7.0) that when you call preparedStatement with more than 7 positional parameters then JDBC will throw this error.

If you have access to Oracle Metalink then one option is to go there and download mentioned patch.

The other solution is workaround - use named parameters instead of positional parameters:

```
INSERT INTO rule_definitions(RULE_DEFINITION_SYS,rule_definition_type,
rule_name,rule_text,rule_comment,rule_message,rule_condition,rule_active,
rule_type,current_value,last_modified_by,last_modified_dttm,
rule_category_sys,recheck_unit,recheck_period,trackable)
VALUES(RULE_DEFINITIONS_SEQ.NEXTVAL,:rule_definition_type,
:rule_name,:rule_text,:rule_comment,:rule_message,:rule_condition,:rule_active,
:rule_type,:current_value,:last_modified_by,:last_modified_dttm,
:rule_category_sys,:recheck_unit,:recheck_period,:trackable)
```

and then use

```
preparedStatement.setStringAtName("rule_definition_type", ...)
```

etc. to set named bind variables for this query.

Comment: It works fine unless generated keys are needed to be returned. At least I still get this error.

I am using spring's template:
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    SqlParameterSource paramSource = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(item);
    simpleJdbcTemplate.getNamedParameterJdbcOperations().update(sql, paramSource, keyHolder, new String[] { "id" });

Any ideas?

Comment: Metalink patch still does not fix the bug in some specific cases.

For example this query does not work neither with patched ojdbc nor with most recent ojdbc version (11.2.0.1.0 ):

select 1 from dual where 1 in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) and 1=:foo

However this query works just fine: 
select 1 from dual where 1 in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) and 1=:foo

Conclusion: don't mix positional and named parameters to avoid this particular problem.

Comment: @Raimonds Can you provide oracle metalink url from where i can download patch ? How to ues that patch? Is there another solution from mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

i am using mybatis + oracle + spring + maven.
Same error "arrayindexoutofboundsexception", if having 8 (or) above parameters.

In pom changed version ojdbc6 to ojdbc14,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

It worked.

Comment: All that remained was to say that you need to reference a repository in your pom file, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, the only thing I can think of is to check that each connection is being accessed in a thread safe manner. The Oracle drivers are usually pretty solid. The only time I've seen weird internal errors like that is when you've got more than one thread accessing the same connection instance and doing weird stuff with it. They aren't thread safe, and should be kept to one per thread.

Answer (score 0):

You create a prepared statement with 15 placeholders, if i understand correct. So you need to pass an array with 15 parameter values to the call. Maybe you missed one or added a surplus one?

Comment: I think it is an extra one too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're passing in the wrong number of parameters. You should be passing in 15, but you're either sending 16 or 14.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah unless my mouse-cursor-counting is off, you're trying to insert 16 values into 15 columns.

Try the same thing SQLPlus*, you should get ORA-00913: too many values

Comment: The number of values and columns in the statement match up by my count.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have access to the oracle.jdbc.PreparedStatement class (and are forced to use java.sql.PreparedStatement, which does not support the methods #setXXXAtName()), the proposed solution to use named parameters is not an option.

I've used the PreparedStatement and GeneratedKeyHolder approach for the mandatory values to be passed (luckily less than 7), and used the generated primary key returned to issue a simple SQL update for the remaining values.