# Java Prepared Statement Error

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

Hi Guys the following code throws me an error i have an insert statement created once and in the while loop i am dynamically setting parameter , and at the end i says ps2.addBatch() again The code that creates dynamic insert

```
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_cols 
where  lower(table_name)= '" + tableName + "' order by column_id"); 
sql = new StringBuffer(300);
sql.append("insert into ").append( tableName).append("(");
String prefix="";
while (rs.next())
{
sql.append(prefix).append(rs.getString("column_name"));
values.append(prefix).append("?");
prefix= ",";

}
sql.append(" ) values(").append(values).append(")");
ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

while ( (eachLine = in.readLine()) != null))
{
    for (int k=stat; k <=45;k++)

{ 
    ps2.setString (k,main[(k-2)]);
}
stat=45;
for (int l=1;l<= 2; l++)
{
    ps2.setString((stat+l),pdp[(l-1)]);// Exception                                       
}

 ps2.addBatch();
```

}

This is the error

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 45
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBDataSetImpl._getDBItem(DBDataSetImpl.java:378)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBDataSetImpl._createOrGetDBItem(DBDataSetImpl.java:781)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBDataSetImpl.setBytesBindItem(DBDataSetImpl.java:2450)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setItem(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1155)
>    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1572)
>    at
>   Processor.main(Processor.java:233)

Comment: I'm not certain how you want us to solve this with so little information...

Comment: then check pdp[] array length^^

Comment: I suppose that you write your forget that java has zero-base arrays. In any case @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams right)

Comment: @pinchi the array has size of 30

Comment: I don't understand how an array length exception of 45 is thrown at that line unless the prepared statement is the problem

Comment: bad question. i'd vote down if i had the rep

Comment: The cause of the error is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277744/jdbc-oracle-arrayindexoutofboundsexception

Comment: @Suresh then edit your question then answer yourself so people will not have to dig in comments for the answer

Answer (score 0):

OP need to clarify. This might help:

```
if(pdp!=null && pdp.length>=l) 
  ps2.setString((stat+l),pdp[(l-1)]);
```

Comment: Perhaps explaining what your solution does will reverse the downvote. I wouldn't worry about the downvote now since you're 29k ;)