# Get last insert id with Oracle 11g using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm new to using Oracle so I'm going off what has already been previously answered in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131064/get-id-of-last-inserted-record-in-oracle-db). I just can't seem to get it to work. Here's the statement that I'm using:

```
declare
  lastId number;
begin
INSERT INTO "DB_OWNER"."FOO" 
  (ID, DEPARTMENT, BUSINESS)
  VALUES (FOO_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'Database Management', 'Oracle')
  RETURNING ID INTO lastId;
end;
```

When I call `executeQuery` the PreparedStatement that I have made, it inserts everything into the database just fine. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to retrieve the ID. The returned ResultSet object will not work for me. Calling

```
if(resultSet.next()) ...
```

yields a nasty SQLException that reads:

> Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement: next

How do I get that `lastId`? Obviously I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: You could always query `SELECT FOO_ID_SEQ.CURRVAL FROM DUAL`.

Comment: Post the function or stored procedure -- need to know if you set `lastid` as an INOUT parameter.

Comment: if i have to execute another query, i'm not guaranteed that it's the id of the element i just inserted. there could be another query that snuck in there.

Comment: `CURRVAL` is session safe, but the `RETURNING` clause will allow you to do two things in one statement.

Comment: @OMGPonies One of the biggest "lightbulb" moments a budding Oracle developer gets to experience ;)

Comment: @OMGPonies, that is all i have. I wrap that query in a PreparedStatement and call executeQuery on it.

Comment: You're running this as an anonymous PLSQL block?  The java resultset object IME needs Oracle to return a SYS_REFCURSOR to iterate through the results - this isn't what an anonymous PLSQL block is intended for, it should be in a stored procedure (preferably within a package).

Comment: ah, well that makes sense. you said that currval is session safe. so that should work for my needs after an insert? i just need the id of the record i just inserted. if that will be safe, i'll just go that route. in the future, i'm planning on making stored procedure, but i need a simple demo for now.

Comment: Use `getGeneratedKeys()`... this is what it's for. I'd also suggest using a trigger to generate the ID rather than using Oracle-specific SQL in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it a function that returns it to you (instead of a procedure).  Or, have a procedure with an OUT parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work, since I've purged all of my computers of anything Oracle, but...

Change your declare to:

```
declare
  lastId OUT number;
```

Switch your statement from a PreparedStatement to a CallableStatement by using prepareCall() on your connection.  Then register the output parameter before your call, and read it after the update:

```
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
cstmt.executeUpdate();
int x = cstmt.getInt(1);
```

Comment: This should work, although the statement must contain a variable `?`: drop the DECLARE section, and replace `RETURNING ID INTO lastId` with `RETURNING ID INTO ?`. Also `getInt` returns an int :)

Comment: Thanks - changed the type of x from byte to int.

Answer (score 2):

I tried with Oracle driver v11.2.0.3.0 (since there are some bugs in 10.x and 11.1.x, see [other blog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280527/995610)). Following code works fine:

```
final String sql = "insert into TABLE(SOME_COL, OTHER_COL) values (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql, new String[] {"ID"});
ps.setLong(1, 264);
ps.setLong(2, 1);
int executeUpdate = ps.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next() ) {
    // The generated id
    long id = rs.getLong(1);
    System.out.println("executeUpdate: " + executeUpdate + ", id: " + id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you prepare the statement set the second parameter to `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`.  Then you should be able to get a `ResultSet` off the statement object.

Comment: @James, possibly but that seems like a strange question, because you really shouldn't have multiple threads working with the same keys and statements.  Could you expand on your question?

Comment: Sure. If you have a single DAO instance (no synchonized) and more than one person working on a database (some sort of server app) this would produce unreliable behaviour. I'm supposing the database returns this value on a first-come, first-served basis so would it suit a single user app? I suppose Hibernate's `EntityManager` handles any issues with state (persisted or not) using a Proxy pattern or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing that in a stored procedure ? According to this [Oracle document](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/jdbcvers.htm#CHDEGDHJ), it won't work with the server-side driver.

```
The Oracle server-side internal driver does not support 
the retrieval of auto-generated keys feature.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Statement.getGeneratedKeys()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) to do this. You just need to make sure to tell JDBC what columns you want back using one of the method overloads for that, such as the `Connection.prepareStatement` overload here:

```
Connection conn = ...
PreparedStatement pS = conn.prepareStatement(sql, new String[]{"id"});
pS.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rS = pS.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rS.next()) {
  long id = rS.getLong("id");
  ...
}
```

You don't need to do the `RETURNING x INTO` stuff with this, just use the basic SQL statement you want.

Comment: long id = rS.getLong("id"); is wrong - you must use column index, instead of name (with oracle)

Comment: @Fisher: I was most definitely using this technique (using the column name) with Oracle. Perhaps there are situations/versions/configurations with Oracle in which it does't work though.