# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when use AutoGeneratedKeys and Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I use ojdbc6-11.1.0.7.0 and when:

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement("Insert into A (b, C) values (?, ?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

I get

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.computeBasicInfo(OracleSql.java:950)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.getSqlKind(OracleSql.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.<init>(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1212)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.<init>(T4CPreparedStatement.java:28)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.allocatePreparedStatement(T4CDriverExtension.java:68)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3140)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3042)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:5890)
```

I just read about this bug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277744/jdbc-oracle-arrayindexoutofboundsexception), but solution does not help because I use Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS feature.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Post more of your code than this one statement.  On one can tell what you've done from this line.

Comment: typo in code or in post: `prepareStatement("Instert` - should be `Insert`

Comment: That bug is for 7 or more parameters.  You have 2.

Comment: @Andreas_D, done, @jzd nope because i get it when i have <7 params and use Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS.

Comment: @Koziolek, I believe you get the same error message, but unless the description of the bug is wrong in the link you are don't meet the criteria for "that" bug.

Comment: @jzd, hm... yes. This bug should call "(7 or more parameters) or (you want use Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)"... ok. this is answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok at this time we make workarount:

- insert without Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS
- because we use sequence to generate ids add additional query that:

  ```
  select seq.currval from dual
  ```

That works fine but we dont have many users and this solution dont protect against multithread problems (we can get wrong Id).

Comment: other option could be: insert 1-6 required params, and then update rest based on  retrieved id

Answer (score -1):

try 
ps = connection.prepareStatement("Insert into A (b, C) values (?, ?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

Answer (score -3):

Please use [ojdbc6.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen) (rather than ojdbc6_g.jar) from oracle. It will solve this problem.

Comment: Why would using the non-debug version of the ojdbc driver fix the problem?

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem.