# NullPointerException when executing PreparedStatement on Oracle DB to insert Blob

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement, blob, sql-insert

does anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong here? I am trying to insert a blob (that contains a pdf in case that matters) into an oracle db together with some additional information. I am using a PreparedStatement

Code:

```
public void saveReportErgebnis(int reportId, Date erzeugung, int archiv,
        Blob pdf, String kommentar) throws Exception {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] tmp = new byte[(int) pdf.length()];
    if(kommentar == null){
        kommentar = "";
    }

    SimpleDateFormat erstellungSdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {
    pdf.getBinaryStream().read(tmp);

    oracle.sql.BLOB oracleBlob = new oracle.sql.BLOB((OracleConnection) getConnection(), tmp);
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = getRTTDBHandler()
            .createPreparedStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO reportergebnis(report_id, erzeugung, archiv, pdf, kommentar) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
    System.out.println("debug 2 oracle");
        prepStmt.setInt(1, reportId);
        prepStmt.setString(2, formatDateString(erstellungSdf.format(erzeugung)));
        prepStmt.setInt(3, archiv);
        prepStmt.setBlob(4, oracleBlob);
        prepStmt.setString(5, kommentar);
        prepStmt.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        loghandler.error(e.toString());
        throw e;
    }

}
```

(formatCode is putting the Date in the right form, e.g. for a return:
date to_date('2013-04-15 09:34:38','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')

When the PrepStatement is executed I get the following Exception:

```
{java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatumBinder.bind(OraclePreparedStatement.java:18279)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setupBindBuffers(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3137)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2355)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3579)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3685)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1088)
        at com.nundp.mc.modules.regressionsTest.db.OracleRTTDBHandler.saveReportErgebnis(OracleRTTDBHandler.java:963)
        at com.nundp.mc.modules.regressionsTest.report.ReportController.executeReport(ReportController.java:237)
        at org.apache.jsp.jsp.modules.Testszenario.ReportHandler_jsp._jspService(ReportHandler_jsp.java:156)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:630)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:535)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
        at org.apache.jsp.jsp.McFrame_jsp._jspService(McFrame_jsp.java:284)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)}
```

I am using Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.3.0.
Help please!

Comment: What is on line 963 of `OracleRTTDBHandler` file?

Comment: Maybe [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277744/jdbc-oracle-arrayindexoutofboundsexception
Hope this helps, Yaron

Comment: But that's for more than 7 positional parameters ?

Comment: Can you change the order and try ? Perhaps BLOB as the last parameter ?

Comment: Yaron: I already looked at that one, but like Noob said, thats if you work with more than 7 parameters or am i missing something?
Noob: I tried, that didn't change anything

Comment: Or is there maybe another way to perform this task?

Comment: Your title says NullPointerException but I see no NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

In my app I used a `File` instead of a `Blob` for the method input and have done the BLOB insert this way:

```
public void insertBlob(String filedesc, File file) {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
        "insert into schema.table values(?,?)");
    pstmt.setString(1, filedesc);
    pstmt.setBinaryStream(2, input);

    pstmt.execute();
}
```

Maybe you will need some `try-catch`, but I hope this will help You.

Comment: +1. In my experience, using setBinaryStream() works much better than any of the alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *createTemporary(yourConnection, false, oracle.sql.BLOB.DURATION_CALL)* function on the oracle.sql.BLOB to create your instance. After that just use the setBytes(...) to set its content.

Answer (score 0):

One remark: `prepStmt.setDate(2, erzeugung);` is simpler.

I would have expected a simple:

```
InputStream blobIS = pdf.getBinaryStream();
prepStmt.setBlob(4, blobIS, pdf.length());

... pdf.free();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must do some sanitary checks before using **setBlob()**

1. check the number of parameters in your db table
2. check the position for the blob.

However ,I would rather recommend you to store only the URl's in the database rather than storing the binary data of the file.

Answer (score 0):

For future searchers, this is how I solved the blob problem:

```
public void saveReportErgebnis(int reportId, Date erzeugung, int archiv,
        Blob pdf, String kommentar) throws Exception {

    byte[] tmp = new byte[(int) pdf.length()];
    if (kommentar == null) {
        kommentar = "";
    }

    try {
        pdf.getBinaryStream().read(tmp);
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = getRTTDBHandler()
                .createPreparedStatement(
                        "INSERT INTO reportergebnis(report_id, erzeugung, archiv, pdf, kommentar) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        prepStmt.setInt(1, reportId);
        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(erzeugung.getTime());
        prepStmt.setTimestamp(2, ts);
        prepStmt.setInt(3, archiv);
        prepStmt.setBytes(4, tmp);
        prepStmt.setString(5, "'" + kommentar + "'");
        prepStmt.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        loghandler.error(e.toString());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much everybody for the help.